# Calling Parse.Cloud.beforeSave() From custom web hooks

Tags: parse-platform

I started off cloning the cloud code example blog app. And in the controllers I have the basic REST crud operations. I tried adding the code here to my controller, as well as just directly in main.js:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.User, function(req, res)
{
  for (var dirtyKey in req.object.dirtyKeys()) {
    if (dirtyKey === "username" || dirtyKey === "email") {
      res.error("User is not allowed to modify " + dirtyKey);
      return;
    }
  }
  res.success();
})
```

In my terminal, I am running `parse develop [app]` to update files as I change. And when I add the above code it does register a trigger.

```
Deploying recent changes...
Your changes are now live.
I2014-07-15T03:30:18.108Z]Deployed v63 with triggers:
  _User:
    before_save
```

Yet I am still able to, from the rest api using postman, able to update the username and email fields.

I suppose, that the real question should be, is that if I am building my app like this; do I still use these beforeSave() triggers like described? Or is it better to simply make those checks in the method (in this case, the User.update method i created) and validate everything there? Because I cant seem to get the triggers to actually run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is a common mistake with how `for..in` works in JavaScript with an array, in your code above `dirtyKey` will be populated with the index, what you want instead is:

```
for (var i in req.object.dirtyKeys()) {
  var dirtyKey = req.object.dirtyKeys()[i];
  if (dirtyKey === "username" || dirtyKey === "email") {
    res.error("User is not allowed to modify " + dirtyKey);
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: Changing that for...in loop did do the trick. But it still doesn't trigger when placed in the controller. Is there a better way I can include this somewhere so it main.js/app.js file isn't cluttered with all of the triggers? I am hoping there is a way to do this in the controller.

Comment: So it looks like there's a mistake in the Parse [blog](http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/parse-objects-dirtykeys/) itself?!

Comment: Definitely a bummer that their documentation is incorrect.